# Getting Bad Access Error

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

I am using `CAShapeLayer` and `UIBezierPath` in my application. I have a reload button. When I am reloading my view several times, it is giving me an `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` error. Here is my code :

```
self.layer.sublayers = nil;
NSInteger numOfDays = [self differenceBetweenTwoDatesFromDate:startDate toDate:endDate];
CGFloat widthOfComponent = numOfDays * dayWidth;
if (self.frame.size.width > widthOfComponent) {
    DLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGRect(self.frame))
    widthOfComponent = self.frame.size.width - 2 * DIFFERENCE_FROM_ORIGIN;
    dayWidth = widthOfComponent/numOfDays;
}
self.frame = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x, self.frame.origin.y, widthOfComponent, self.frame.size.height);

[self reloadData];

[super layoutSubviews];
```

I am getting this error when I am passing the new frame to `self.frame`.

Comment: `self.frame` is getting released..

Comment: but hows that possible ?

Comment: what is `self`? And no, `self.frame` does not get released.

Comment: self is my UIView instance which i am reloading from view controller.

Comment: Can you please share the crash log? At which line its being crashed?

Answer (score 0):

It's caused by `self.layer.sublayers = nil`. Indiscriminately removing all sublayers causes nasty crashes in iOS 7, which can occur much later in the program's execution. I have tested this thoroughly using both `rootLayer.sublayers = nil` and `[rootLayer.sublayers makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)]`. There must be a system-created layer that's getting messed up.

You have to keep your own array of layers and remove them yourself:

```
[myArrayOfLayersIAdded makeObjectsPerformSelector:@selector(removeFromSuperlayer)];
```